# I'm creating a chat application and attempting to implement custom emotes similar to twitch's emotes. Am I on the right path?

Tags: javascript

Currently I have a functioning real time chat application which works fine but I'm trying to bedazzle it a little bit and thought that custom emotes would be the a nice addition.

My main idea is that I would have a JSON file which would contain all custom emotes. For example:

```
[
    {
        keyword: "LOL",
        url: "imageUrl1"
    },
    {
        keyworld: "HAHA",
        url: "imageUrl2"
    }
]
```

So whenever a message is received, I'd have to split the message into `<span></span>` elements and replace the keyword for the emote with a span that contains the image of the icon. For example:

```
That was so funny LOL. Do it again!
```

Would be split into 3 spans

```
<span>That was so funny <span>
<span class='LOL'></span>
<span>.Do it again!</span>
```

and the span element with class LOL would have the emote URL as background-image. I'm curious if that's a good way to do it? Frankly I'm not quite sure how would I iterate over the messages and slice them up right now but I'll figure it out.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: sounds good. You can `.split` on a regex.

Comment: The unstyled spans aren't doing anything, so you can leave these out and only wrap the emotes in spans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. Your application can scan over each message and modify it before displaying it. The part you're unsure about is really the tricky part. The way to do this depends a lot on knowing what all of your valid characters are and what ones will be used to identify emotes. From the examples you provided it seems pretty simple. It looks like you have some unique "words" that you want to find in the message and replace.

In Javascript, you could do something like the following:

```js
let message = 'That was so funny LOL. Do it again!'
const emotes = [
    {
        keyword: "LOL",
        url: "imageUrl1"
    },
    {
        keyworld: "HAHA",
        url: "imageUrl2"
    }
]

emotes.forEach(emote => {
  message = message.replace(emote.keyword, `<span class="${emote.keyword}"></span>`)
})

console.log(message) // That was so funny <span class="LOL"></span>. Do it again!
```

Note that in this approach not everything gets surrounded by a `span` tag. Only the emotes get replaced.